# Wordpress Menu with featured images and description

Tags: wordpress

I've followed [this tutorial](http://wpsmith.net/2011/tutorials/how-to-add-menu-descriptions-featured-images-to-wordpress-menu-items/) to create Wordpress menu items with description and featured images. You can see the result [here](http://sitoprova12345.altervista.org/) on the righ hand side of the screen.

Now there's a problem: Is there a way to make the images clickable?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but since there is no solution posted, this is what you do if you are having the same problem.

After following the tutorial mentioned above, you will have this line of code somewhere in functions.php:

```
    $args['thumbnail_link'] = false;
```

Just change to:

```
    $args['thumbnail_link'] = true;
```

And you are done. Your thumbnails will now link to their respective pages. If you want more control over the image's URL, that's a bit more complicated so you'll need to search for other solutions.